# Bluetooth gatt connection global variable not changing

Tags: c, global-variables, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, nrf52

I have an issue of an if statement not passing whilst my system gatt connection is not made.

**Context**

I have a BLE system using a NRF52840-dk board programmed in C. I also have a mobile application which, communicates with this board via a Gatt connection. I have a single service with a single characteristic. I write to this characteristic from my mobile application and, from this do some processing. At the moment I can send over a timestamp and begin storing data. However, I need to then send data back to my mobile device by this connection.

So what I have is a command to be sent from the phone to ask for some data. This should then send data back to the phone by changing the characteristic value.

Before I can change the value I need to see if the command has been issued. However, due to the priorities and constraints of the device I need to do this processing in the main function not in the BLE interrupt that I have done my time stamping in. This is due to the data I will be transmitting eventually will be large.

My issue however is, I receive the command to send some data back to the phone and update a global int value (changed from 0 to 1). Then in my main loop test this value and, if it is 1 write to the terminal and change the value back. I would then use this point of the code to run a function to send the data.

But this statement does not pass.

This is my main loop code

```
    if(GATT_CONNECTED == false)//This works!
    {
        //Do some functions here
    }
    else if (GATT_CONNECTED == true)// GATT_CONNECTED = true
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Test1 passed");//Testing variable this does not print
        if(main_test == 1)
        {
            NRF_LOG_INFO("Test2 passed");//This does not print either irrelevant of value
            main_test = 0;//False
        }
        idle_state_handle();
    }
```

I don't know if the issue is the way I have defined my variable or due to interrupt priorities or something like that. But, when my Gatt connection is made the loop of (GATT_CONNECTED == true) does not seem to process.

My variable is defined in another file where my GATT connection is handled. The GATT connected variable is handled in main. my main_test variable is defined in another c file as int main_test = 0;. In the header declared as extern int main_test;.

I know the GATT_CONNECTED variable works as I have code in it that only runs when my gatt is not connected. I have omitted it for simplicity.

Any ideas,

Thanks

Ps Hope you are all keeping well and, safe

Edit

Added code for simplicity

main.c

```
bool GATT_CONNECTED = false;

int main(void)
{
    Init_Routine();

    while(1)
    {
        Process_data();//This runs if the gatt is not connected if statement inside
        if(GATT_CONNECTED == true)//This does not run true when the gatt is connected
        {
            NRF_LOG_INFO("check gatt connectedpassed");//Testing variable.
            nrf_gpio_pin_set(LED_4);//Turn an LED on once led 4 does not work
        }
        idle_state_handle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it still not work if you mark the global variable `volatile`?

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it did not work. Good idea though.

Comment: How exactly is and where  `GATT_CONNECTED` defined?

Comment: GATT_CONNECTED is defined as a bool in the top of main. It is only used inside of the main code itself. It changes to 1 when a connected is made. 0 when the connection is disconnected.

Comment: What changes it?  Can you either include some code (better option) , or at least explain how `GATT_CONNECTED` is set.  I see no assignment statement in anything you have shown.  Normally, something that is globally defined, and needs to respond to an external process is created as `volatile`.  I am surprised it is not.

Comment: It would be best if you could include a [mcve].  If your code is large and complicated, then create an example that has been scaled down and simplified for the purpose of illustrating how you have constructed the part that updates this variable.  If your app runs more than one thread, then make sure you explain how the threads accommodate each other, i.e. so that critical things are not blocked, or how global variables are shared. etc, etc.  Although this seems interesting and very solvable, without more information it won't be solved here.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is that even though the variable GATT_CONNECTED is set to 1 inside my GATT connection function. The main loop does not see it. I don't know why but my main loop is not processing when the connection is made.

Comment: Does your project include a header file that you can declare a custom variable in?  (i.e. one that is not part of a 3rd party library, that should not be edited.)  And are you running more than one thread?

Comment: I have a custom header file which some of my Gatt connection stuff happens inside of. As this is where my custom ble gatt service is defined. So yes I do use header files for this project. Also no I am not running more than one thread. But I believe the program returns to the main loop once my event processing is complete.

Comment: I see your edited in code.  It seems like `Process_data();` should be encapsulated in an `else` branch of your `if` construct.  i.e. `if(GATT_CONNECTED == true) {do this}else{do that}`.  The only thing that should _always_ run in the course of an iteration of the loop is one _OR_ the other of the two branches, and the `sleep` function and   (which I assume is `idle_state_handle();`)

Comment: @ryyker I have changed the loops as you suggested. Unfortunately it did not solve my issue. I suspect I could be staying in my Gatt connection and not returning to the main function. But I am not sure if this is the case or not.

Comment: If you have not used a debugger, [like this one for example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) that allows you to set break points and step through your code one line at a time, I suggest it is time to do that.  Then you would not have to guess whether you _"could be staying in my Gatt connection and not returning to the main function"_